# Deleting Amazon account

Tags: account-management, amazon, delete

If I permanently delete my Amazon account and make a new one with the same email / payment details… will my order history be intact or deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=GDK92DNLSGWTV6MP), or how I read it, is that everything in the account will become inaccessible. So most likely creating a new account will be an empty one.

Want to be sure? Contact [Amazon support](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html).

*I have no affiliation with any of Amazon's services or products.*